# django/uwsgi/nginx invalid HTTP protocol

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

Any idea why this error happen when accessing nginx?

uwsgi is running with the command:

`/usr/sbin/uwsgi --socket /home/user/run/project.sock --chmod-socket --pidfile /home/user/project/uwsgi.pid --module project.wsgi_app --pythonpath /home/user/ -p 4`

**/home/user/project/wsgi_app.py**:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.append('/home/user/project')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

uwsgi uses its own protocl.  you can put nginx in front of it to serve it, or just as a test you can add the parameters "--http-only --http :8080" to get a http server running to view your site.